# Best way to storing week days in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, type-conversion

I would like to know the most efficient datatype of storing days (*SUNDAY, MONDAY* etc.) of the week in a MySQL database. I want to search using that field and it will be used frequently.

I want to show the days as *SUNDAY, MONDAY* etc. in the GUI also. So, is it ok to use **VARCHAR** and store it as same as the name of the day or store it as **TINYINT** and convert when showing in the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
CREATE TABLE DAY_TABLE
(
 -- other fields
  EVENT_DAY ENUM('SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')
);
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than using VARCHAR or TINYINT?

Comment: why?? u can easily use your query on this.